# Composite Component, IllegalStateException: Component ID has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

Since I have upgraded to WildFly 8 I have problems with my JSF custom components: the first time the custom component is loaded, an error is throw:

```
IllegalStateException: Component ID formDlgPesqPccs:pesqOcupacaoCC:pesquisaOcupacaoDlg:pesquisaOcupacaoDlgbuttonpesquisaOcupacao has already been found in the view.
```

After first time, the component is rendered normally. I'm using Mojarra 2.2.10.

The composite component (pesquisarOcupacao.xhtml):

```
<composite:interface>       
    <composite:attribute name="beanReference" 
        type="seb.sarh.pccs.PesquisarOcupacaoBean" required="true"/>                
    <composite:attribute name="updatePesquisa" required="true"/>        
    <composite:attribute name="pesquisaScrollHeight" required="true"/>  
    <composite:attribute name="estilo" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="estiloPesquisa" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="edicao" default="true"/>                         
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>


    <div id="divWraperPesqOcupacao" style="#{cc.attrs.estilo}">

        <p:panel styleClass="panelgrid">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:fieldset legend="Tipo da Pesquisa">
                    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.tipo}"
                        requiredMessage="Selecione o tipo de pesquisa.">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Cargo  " />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Função" />                           
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </p:fieldset>

                <p:fieldset legend="Criterio da Pesquisa">
                    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.criterio}"
                        requiredMessage="Selecione o criterio de pesquisa.">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Código" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Descrição" />                            
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </p:fieldset>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>          

        <div id="divPesquisa" class="reference" style="clear: left">

            <p:fieldset legend="Texto a pesquisar" style="#{cc.attrs.estiloPesquisa} ">

                <p:commandButton id="#{cc.id}buttonpesquisaOcupacao"
                    style="float: right"
                    update="#{cc.attrs.updatePesquisa}"
                    actionListener="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.pesquisarOcupacao}"
                    icon="ui-icon-search" process="@form" />

                <div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 15px 0 0; margin-right: 4px">
                    <p:inputMask id="cod" value="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.texto}"
                    mask="?99999" rendered="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.criterio == 2}"
                    style="width: 100%" />
                <p:inputText id="desc" value="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.texto}"
                    rendered="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.criterio == 1}"
                    style="width: 100%" />
                </div>

            </p:fieldset>   
        </div>          

        <div id="divExpandPesqEstrutura" class="expand">

            <p:fieldset id="#{cc.id}fldsetOcupacoesPesquisadas"
                styleClass="expand-content" legend="Resultados da Pesquisa"
                style="#{cc.attrs.estiloPesquisa}">

                <p:dataTable id="datatable" styleClass="corner" emptyMessage=""
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.selecaoPesquisa}"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.listOcupacoes}" var="cargo"
                    scrollable="true" rowKey="#{cargo.hashCode()}"
                    scrollHeight="#{cc.attrs.pesquisaScrollHeight}">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                        listener="#{cc.attrs.beanReference.onRowSelect}" />

                    <p:column width="10%">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Código" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{cargo.codigo}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="68%">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{cargo.descricao}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.edicao}">
                        <p:column width="10%" style="text-align:center">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:commandButton id="editarOcupacaoButton" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                style="width: 20px; height: 20px" />
                            <p:tooltip for="editarOcupacaoButton"
                                value="Editar Cargo/Função" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column width="10%" style="text-align:center">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:commandButton id="excluirOcupacaoButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                style="width: 20px; height: 20px" />
                            <p:tooltip for="excluirOcupacaoButton"
                                value="Excluir Cargo/Função" />
                        </p:column>
                    </c:if>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:fieldset>

        </div>

    </div>

</composite:implementation>
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

```
<display-name>SARH</display-name>

<error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code> 
    <location>/xhtml/error.xhtml</location> 
</error-page> 

<error-page> 
    <error-code>500</error-code> 
    <location>/xhtml/error.xhtml</location> 
</error-page> 

<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/xhtml/error.xhtml</location> 
</error-page> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>               
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>redmond</param-value>
</context-param>    

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>             
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/xhtml/selecionar_empresa.xhtml</welcome-file>                
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <display-name>RelatorioServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RelatorioServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>seb.sarh.util.RelatorioServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RelatorioServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RelatorioServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>                   
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Comment: How is your JSF state saving configured (in `web.xml`)? And to be sure, you're really talking about true "custom components" and not actually about "composite components"?

Comment: BalusC the state saving is configured as default (server, I think). You're right, it's a composite component.

Comment: What if you set `javax.faces.SERIALIZE_SERVER_STATE` context param to `true`?

Comment: The same situation, BalusC.